# Free Modeling Tool

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Application to help build diagrams](https://superuser.com/questions/67536/application-to-help-build-diagrams)

I am looking for a free modeling tool.  Something that I can use to easily make Squares and Circles and connect them with lines.

Mostly I am looking for something fast and easy to use.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I assume on Windows judging by your other questions?

Comment: Are you looking for a diagram drawing tool, a 2D drawing CAD or 3D CAD tool (usually called "modeling") ?

Comment: I should have been more clear.  I am using windows and looking fora  diagram tool.

Comment: In that case this is a duplicate ... http://superuser.com/questions/67536/application-to-help-build-diagrams

Comment: Indeed it is.  Sorry, I should have searched harder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about [Dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/)? It's a free Visio alternative, available for Windows and Linux.

Very easy to use:

[image]

Comment: +1 - what I would use, IMHO, not as good as Visio, but a very good free alternative

Comment: You're most welcome :)

Comment: Agreed - it's not Visio, but it's free, and you can't beat the price!